# Gimp GEGL Tutorial for Photographers?

Tags: photo-editing, gimp, tutorial

Is there a good tutorial for GIMP 2.8 software, that explains, comprehensively, how to use the 
 **GEGL  operations**
 (which have the the advantage of being **nondestructive**) for photo images?

When I look for tutorials, I find only very basic tutorials or some documentation that is targeted to developers, or deprecated stuff. I am interested in using the GEGL enabled features in GIMP for photo ediing, from the perspective of an end user. At this time, this is poorly documented.

I want to do only tasks of intermediate complexity in GIMP, e.g. retouching, clipping, layering. No color space conversions, no algorithmical, context-dependent void-filling  etc

Comment: I think this question does not belong here, being very much a software-development question (use of a sofware API).

Comment: No, not a software development question, I just want to use GEGL-enabled GIMP features, as an end user interested in photo editing

Comment: Could you give an idea of what you mean, why CEGL-specific documentation is important? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You can do imaging operations in a reversible manner, even after saving and re-opening. At this time GIMP's GEGL operations are in a single Menu (Tools/GEGL operation...) without much grouping, and some operations don't work so well. I just tried the "Rotate" operation, and the values were pre-poulated with idiotic defaults (after setting them manually it works). Still it is a usability nightmare, and maybe someone has worked out a set of clever customizations and best practices.

Comment: For the records, these operations do not work non-destructively in GIMP 2.8 yet. They are more comparable to the existing tools.

Answer (score 2):

I think the basic answer here is: you see only seeing developer-oriented documentation because this is an unfinished feature.  If you're looking for end-user documentation, wait for Gimp 3.10, where GEGL is the default, and then all of the up-to-date docs will automatically apply. (And, really, you probably won't need 'em, because it'll just be in-place replacements for all of the operations you are used to.)

This is particularly the case because the *UI* is also in current development with a lot of changes; end-user documentation really is premature.

If you are interested in trying this *now*, you could build your own (or on Fedora [follow these instructions](http://www.ryanlerch.org/blog/gimp-goat-invasion-builds/) to enable Ryan Lerch's Copr containing development builds.